# The diag() function in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to use the `diag()` function in a Matrix without using the built-in function or iteration?

```
   M<-matrix(1:9, ncol=3) # make a matrix 

    q5b<-function(M){ #function

    }
```

I know that `M[1,1]`, `M[2,2]`, and `M[3,3]` will give me the same output as `diag(M)`. However, I can't think of a way to do this without a for loop.

My thought process was I should have a condition where `row index == column index` in the Matrix then print that value. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the functions `row` and `col` to find the indices where the column number is identical to the row number:

```
row(M) == col(M)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

M[row(M) == col(M)]
# [1] 1 5 9
```

Comment: Nice solution, but any idea why it's so much slower than `diag` or my alternative?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks for the tests. I assume my solution is slower because two integer matrices have to be created whose size is identical to the reference matrix. After this all values in these matrices are compared using `==`. Hence, the solution is not very efficient.

Answer (score 8):

Just subset based on another matrix:

```
> diag(M)
[1] 1 5 9
> M[matrix(rep(sequence(ncol(M)), 2), ncol = 2)]
[1] 1 5 9
```

The above would run into a problem in a non-square matrix, so we modify it as below.

As your function, one answer for question 5b could be:

```
q5b <- function(M) { 
  A <- sequence(ncol(M))[sequence(min(nrow(M), ncol(M)))]
  M[cbind(A, A)]
}
```

---

#### Update: Benchmarks are always fun

```
library(microbenchmark)

fun1 <- function(M) diag(M)
fun2 <- function(M) M[row(M) == col(M)]
fun3 <- function(M) {
  A <- sequence(ncol(M))[sequence(min(nrow(M), ncol(M)))]
  M[cbind(A, A)]
}    

set.seed(1)
M <- matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), ncol = 1000)

microbenchmark(fun1(M), fun2(M), fun3(M), times = 100)
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr       min        lq     median        uq        max neval
#  fun1(M)  4654.825  4747.408  4822.8865  4912.690   5877.866   100
#  fun2(M) 53270.266 54813.606 55059.0695 55749.062 200384.531   100
#  fun3(M)    66.284    82.321   118.8835   129.361    191.155   100
```